# How to Convert Tree output of minspantree to matrix

Tags: matlab

I am using 
[Tree, pred] = minspantree(BGObj) function of Matlab
The out Pred is a vector containing predecessor nodes information.and the output Tree is a sparse matrix and looks like

```
(1,2) 1
(1,3) 1
(3,5) 1
```

In parenthesis 1 represents destination, 2 represents source and 1 in-front of parenthesis represents weights.
I need to put source and destination nodes to another matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
[dest,  source, weight] = find(Tree);
```

This will give you the results below:

```
Tree =

   (1,2)        1
   (1,3)        1
   (3,5)        1

[dest,  source, weight] = find(Tree)

dest =

     1
     1
     3
source =

     2
     3
     5
```

If you want this in a single matrix:

```
idx = [dest, source];
```

Comment: share the link from where i can accept the answer.i am unable to find it onthis page

Comment: It should be right under the vote up/vote down buttons. It's a V-shaped thing that will turn green when you click it. Thanks!